# Javascript Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined after fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I tried looking at other questions but I can't find a proper solution. I'm retrieving a GET response and I'm storing it into a variable, then I'm parsin that array in order to find daily occurrences. The code works, but once it reaches the forEach it complains with:

```
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

. Here's my code:

```
var myObj;
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data)
.then(() => console.log(myObj));

var myRes = [];

myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
    var date = elem.CreationDate.split(' ')[0];


    if (myRes [date]) {
        myRes [date] += 1;
    } else {
        myRes [date] = 1;
    }
});
```

That's the content of myObj once it finished:

```
[{Id, Var1, Var2, CreationDate},
{1, 123, Var2, 2020-12-11},
{2, 1234, Var2, 2020-12-12},
{3, 12345, Var2, 2020-12-12},
{4, 1234, Var2, 2020-12-13},
{5, 321, Var2, 2020-12-15},
{6, 3214, Var2, 2020-12-15},
{7, 5432, Var2, 2020-12-16}]
```

where am I wrong? If I'm executing the code in different steps it works correctly.

EDIT:
Here's my updated code:

```
var myObj;
var myRes= [];
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data)
.then(() => {
myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
    var date = elem.CreationDate.split(' ')[0];
    if (myRes[date]) {
        myRes[date] += 1;
    } else {
        myRes[date] = 1;
    }
});

});

var finalResult= {};
dates.forEach(date => {
    if(!myRes.hasOwnProperty(date)) {
        finalResult[date] = 0;
    } else {
        finalResult[date] = myRes[date];
    }
    return finalResult;
});
```

If I'm executing the whole my finalResult is empty, while if I'm executing it in blocks it works. If I'm inserting the myRes =[] inside the last .then it complains it can't find it. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You can't return the data from a fetch like this. Either put everything relying on `myObj` in a then, or use aysnc/await.

Comment: but this is working correctly if I'm executing the code in two steps. How can I solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I tried but I cannot understand how to solve. In need to perform some operations on that object once I have retrieved the values in it

Comment: You can. Either do the operations inside an attached then, or await the fetch.

Comment: like `async function fetchJson() {
  var myObj;
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data)
.then(() => console.log(myObj));
  // waits until the request completes...
}var myRes = [];

myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
    var date = elem.CreationDate.split(' ')[0];


    if (myRes [date]) {
        myRes [date] += 1;
    } else {
        myRes [date] = 1;
    }
});`

Comment: Try `var myObj = await fetch ...` and remove `.then(data=>myObj= data) .then(() => console.log(myObj));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Duplicated: you might prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/).

### Edit: accessing response from outside of `then()`

#### Short answer:

**You can't.**

#### Long answer:

What you are doing is an **asynchronous** operation. It means that we don't know how long it will take.

Given an example code below, let's say `fetch()` takes 5 seconds to complete.

```js
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1').then(doOtherThings);

someTaskAfterFetch();

console.log('Done');
```

How long will it take until you see 'Done' in console after you run this code? The answer is **immediately**.

#### What's happening?

Let's see what happens.

```
    ===       fetch(url).then(doOtherThings) --> 'Start' fetching, without waiting for result.
     |               |
     |               |                       --> You expect fetch to be done here, which will not happen.
     |               |
     |        someTaskAfterFetch()           --> At this moment you see no fetch result.
almost 0 sec         |
     |               |
     |        console.log('Done')
     |               |
    ===       'Done' is printed
     |               |
     |               |
about 5 sec   (in some future)
     |               |
     |               |
    ===       **Fetch completed**             --> Fetch is finished here.
                     |
              doOtherThings(result)           --> doOtherThings, which we passed to `then()` will be run here.
```

Execution starts with `fetch(url).then(doOtherThings)` at line 1.

Then **immediately** continues to `someTaskAfterFetch()` at line 2.

Right after that, moves to `console.log('done')`.

In a near future(about 5 seconds after), the fetch you started finally completes, and `doOtherThings` is called with the result.

#### How to deal with the result?

You have to separate **calling** and **waiting** when thinking about an asynchronous task. You started a fetch task by calling `fetch()` but didn't wait for the result.

To handle the fetch result:

- You can wait until a task finishes([async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))
- Or tell what to do when fetch is completed.

Using `then()` is the second approach. You can pass all of your result handling code to `then()`.

For more detailed answer, you might like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/).

---

In your code,

```js
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data)
.then(() => console.log(myObj));
```

This line will return immediately.

Right after that,

```js
myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
    var date = elem.CreationDate.split(' ')[0];


    if (myRes [date]) {
        myRes [date] += 1;
    } else {
        myRes [date] = 1;
    }
});
```

The `forEach` will be called.

At that moment, *requesting a fetch job* is quickly finished before the `forEach`. However, the *fetching* itself might not have finished at that time.

The functions you passed to the following `then()` calls will be launched after the fetching is successfully finished.

You can pass your `forEach` code to the `then()` method:

```js
var myObj;
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => myObj = data)
.then(() => console.log(myObj));
.then(() => {
    var myRes = [];

    myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
        var date = elem.CreationDate.split(' ')[0];


        if (myRes [date]) {
            myRes [date] += 1;
        } else {
            myRes [date] = 1;
        }
    });

    // And other stuffs to do with myRes.
})
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/ Please may you mark it as such?

Comment: Updated my question with an issue

Comment: @Potados how can I access my variable from outside? Like I described in my edit

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved using a `setTimeout()`

Comment: @thranduil90 that will only cover up the issue. It will fail when the fetch takes longer than the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Because your fetch & then is a async operation, you need to execute forEach in then function like below:

```
var myObj;
fetch('https://blashblashblash.com?param1')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=>myObj= data)
.then(() => {
    console.log(myObj);
    var myRes = [];

    myObj.forEach(function (elem) {
        var date = elem.CreationDate.split(' ')[0];


        if (myRes [date]) {
            myRes [date] += 1;
        } else {
            myRes [date] = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call. Please may you mark it as such?

Comment: thanks! But I then need to access the myRes element and in that case it says it's not defined. How can I access it afterwards?

Comment: @thranduil90 You can access `myRes` in the `then(() => { ... })` block.

Comment: @thranduil90 Not outside the `then` you can't.

Comment: Can I declare it near myObj and access it afterwards?

Comment: @thranduil90 inside the `then`?

Comment: Updated the question with the issue. I can't access it inside the `then`

Comment: @thranduil90 did you see my reply to your comment?